# Why is 生地黃 called 地黃 [yellow earth]?

Tags: etymology

Does anyone know the reason why 生地黃 is called 地黃 [yellow earth]? I don't know if 六味地黄丸 took the name from 生地黃 or viceversa, but either way I couldn't find neither the etymology of 六味地黄丸 in English (I still can't understand Chinese properly). Any idea for the reason of the presence of 地黄 in the two?

Comment: http://baike.baidu.com/view/301248.htm reason for yellow： 形态特征：。。。根茎肉质，鲜时黄色.
reason for  地黄 in 六味地黄丸：  http://www.baike.com/wiki/%E5%85%AD%E5%91%B3%E5%9C%B0%E9%BB%84%E4%B8%B8 ：
六味地黄丸由六味中药材组成，其中熟地黄为君药（monarch drug in a prescription），故名为六味地黄丸。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

黃 is sometimes a plant name: 大黃 'rhubarb' (this used to be dai-huang, not da-huang), 麻黃 ephedra'; 地 sometimes means a tuber, seems that's not the case here. One source identifies 3 varieties: 天黃, 人黃, 地黃.  This is the 三合 system.

Comment: see above quote,根茎 （rhizome; rootstock; tuber; rhizoma; rootstalk）肉质 ，鲜时黄色

Comment: Good catch!  (nice hat,too)

Answer (score 0):

地黄 is the plant, Rehmannia glutinosa. For TCM, it can be used in various ways:

- fresh: 鲜地黄（生地黄、鲜生地）
- dried: 干地黄（生地黄、干生地）
- processed: 熟地黄（熟地）

生 (raw) is usually a synonym to 鲜 (fresh), but here also means unprocessed and therefore equivalent to either 鲜 (fresh) or 干 (dry).

[https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/地黃](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%9C%B0%E9%BB%83)